# Peticion fetch retorna error 401

Tags: javascript

Al realizar el tipeo en un input me da el error 401. Realizo la petición con el mismo barrer token desde postman y la petición funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

```
 fetch(`https://api.genius.com/search?q=${valorBusqueda}`, {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "same-origin",
       
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer TOKEN",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "authorizationToken": "allow"
        },
      }).then((respuestaBusqueda) => {
          respuestaBusqueda.json().then((listadoBusqueda) => {
          console.log(listadoBusqueda);
        });
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice algo similar con una API privada(es decir que necesita un TOKEN). Por lo que veo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```js
fetch('https://api.genius.com/search?q=${valorBusqueda}', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEEEEEEEN'
    }
  }) //fetch
  //Consumo de la promesa
  .then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
  .then(error => console.log(error))
```